# Asp Core 3 - How to allow nullable [FromBody] object in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Let's say I have a simple controller with one POST method that accepts an object from its body. However, the presence of this object should be optional in the HTTP request body. I tried to implement this behavior with the following code

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class GreetingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string SayHello([FromBody] User user = null)
    {
        return "Hello " + user?.Name;
    }
}
```

If I make a request with an object in the body, everything works fine. But with this configuration, it is unable to make a POST request with empty body. If I create a request without `Content-Type` header (as there is actually no content), I get the following error:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "|192e45d5-4bc216316f8d3966."
}
```

if the `Content-Type` header has value `application/json` then the response looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|192e45d6-4bc216316f8d3966.",
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "A non-empty request body is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

So, how to make the object optional in the request body? It is quite common problem and I am curious if there is a simple solution for that in ASP Core 3. I don't want to read the object from Request stream and deserialize it on my own.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is now an easier way (since 5.0-preview7)

You can now achieve this per action method, by configuring a `FromBodyAttribute` property named `EmptyBodyBehavior`

Demonstration:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody(EmptyBodyBehavior = EmptyBodyBehavior.Allow)] MyModel model)
```

Thanks to LouraQ's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387180/asp-core-3-how-to-allow-nullable-frombody-object-in-controller-method#comment108677015_61403203), which guided me towards the above [answer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6878#issuecomment-647830903) on github

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Awesome! But I'd recommend to make the object itself nullable as well: "MyModel? model"

Comment: Calling from Postman v10, be sure to add `Content-Type = application/json` on the Headers tab, which got automatically deleted when there was no request body. Without "Content-Type", I was still getting the "Unsupported media type" error, which took a while to figure out!

Comment: Instead of adding `Content-Type` in the Postman headers, you can alternately [add missing content-type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73109795/13191303)

Answer (score 8):

Right now, the only way is via a global option, `MvcOptions.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding`. It defaults to `false`, so you just need to do:

```
services.AddControllers(o =>
{
    o.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would prefer non-global configuration. It works well but I need to send `content-type` header, despite the empty request body. Otherwise I get `Unsupported Media Type` as I mentioned above. It is strange that such common functionality is not covered in ASP.

Comment: There's no per action method built in. It's all or nothing.

Comment: Just as a comment to help someone else: If you're using AddMvcCore, this is an option on the options for that command as well so you don't have to use AddControllers to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your final intention, but if you don't want to choose the content-type, you can pass `an empty json string`.

At this time, the user is not empty, but `the content of it's field's value is null`, and the final result is the same. Maybe you You can try it.

Here is the debug process with the postman:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of that but I want to find a solution that works with empty response body (not just an empty json object).

Comment: @Mayo, I think @ Chris Pratt has provided the solution. In addition, there is no better one, you can refer to the discussion in github:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6878

Answer (score 0):

You could create as simple wrapper class that is never `null`. The wrapper has a field that can be either `null` or not. That's how the front end can pass a `null` user when needed.

```
public class UserWrapper // or call it SayHelloRequestBody
{
    public User User { get; set; } // this can be null
}
```